Equivalent of pandas.Series.dt.ceil in polars
I'm trying to round timestamp to the next minutes in polars.
For example:

2023-01-01 10:05:00 should stay 2023-01-01 10:05:00
2023-01-01 10:05:01 should be 2023-01-01 10:06:00

This works in pandas with ceil:
import polars as pl
import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {'timestamp' :[
        datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 5, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 5, 30),
        datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 6, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 6, 1),
    ]
    }
)




timestamp




2023-01-01T10:05:00.000000


2023-01-01T10:05:30.000000


2023-01-01T10:06:00.000000


2023-01-01T10:06:01.000000



df['timestamp'].to_pandas().dt.ceil('1min')




timestamp




2023-01-01T10:05:00.000000


2023-01-01T10:06:00.000000


2023-01-01T10:06:00.000000


2023-01-01T10:07:00.000000



The only way I found in polars is the following:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('timestamp').dt.truncate('1m') == pl.col('timestamp'))
    .then(pl.col('timestamp'))
    .otherwise(pl.col('timestamp').dt.truncate('1m') + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
)


There was a feature request for it: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11936 - The result being it was added to the polars-xdt plugin.

you can use polars-xdt for this
installation:
pip install polars-xdt

usage:
import polars_xdt as xdt

df.with_columns(timestamp_ceil = xdt.ceil('timestamp', '1m'))

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ timestamp_ceil      │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 10:05:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:05:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 10:05:30 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:06:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 10:06:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:06:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 10:06:01 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:07:00 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

